# Dockerfile alpine apk add using ARG to pin version fails

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

I have a docker file that as follows:

```
ARG ALPINE_VERSION=3.16.2
ARG GLAB_VERSION="1.22.0"
ARG JQ_VERSION="1.6"

FROM alpine:$ALPINE_VERSION

RUN apk add --no-cache "glab~=${GLAB_VERSION}" "jq~=${JQ_VERSION}"

ENTRYPOINT [ "glab" ]
```

When I try to build the image, I get an error because it is unable to resolve the version of glab:

```
docker build -t gitlab/glab:latest .
[+] Building 6.6s (5/5) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 258B                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:3.16.2                                                                                                                                                                                   2.0s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:3.16.2@sha256:bc41182d7ef5ffc53a40b044e725193bc10142a1243f395ee852a8d9730fc2ad                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => ERROR [2/2] RUN apk add --no-cache "glab~=${GLAB_VERSION}" "jq~=${JQ_VERSION}"                                                                                                                                                                 4.4s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 > [2/2] RUN apk add --no-cache "glab~=${GLAB_VERSION}" "jq~=${JQ_VERSION}":                                                                                                                                                                            
#5 1.009 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz                                                                                                                                                                  
#5 1.880 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#5 4.227 ERROR: 'glab~=' is not a valid world dependency, format is name(@tag)([<>~=]version)
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache "glab~=${GLAB_VERSION}" "jq~=${JQ_VERSION}"]: exit code: 99
```

If I update the Dockerfile to use hardcoded values:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache "glab~=1.22.0" "jq~=1.6"
```

it works:

```
docker build -t gitlab/glab:latest .
[+] Building 17.5s (6/6) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 239B                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:3.16.2                                                                                                                                                                                   0.6s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/alpine:3.16.2@sha256:bc41182d7ef5ffc53a40b044e725193bc10142a1243f395ee852a8d9730fc2ad                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [2/2] RUN apk add --no-cache "glab~=1.22.0" "jq~=1.6"                                                                                                                                                                                         16.6s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.2s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.2s 
 => => writing image sha256:46bccd18a999a696ef9e80fb75983a6b5655a774b88b1412b55707cb152823e5                                                                                                                                                       0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/gitlab/glab:latest                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
```

Is it possible to use ARG to set the versions somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was becuase I was specifying the `GLAB_VERSION` and `JQ_VERSION` **before** the `FROM ...` instruction.

Updating the Dockerfile as follows works:

```
ARG ALPINE_VERSION=3.16.2
FROM alpine:$ALPINE_VERSION

ARG GLAB_VERSION=1.22.0
ARG JQ_VERSION="1.6"

RUN apk add --no-cache "glab~=${GLAB_VERSION}" "jq~=${JQ_VERSION}"

ENTRYPOINT [ "glab" ]
```